# Как изменить аргументы в передаваемых функциях?

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-apps

Имеется следующий код:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    Route('/', HomePageHandler, 'main'),
    .....,
    Route('/sign_up', SignUpHandler, 'sign_up')], 
    debug=True, config=config)
```

Хочу изменить аргумент для всех функций. Чисто теоретически можно взять создать отдельный список и его передать:

```
lst_route = [
    Route('/', HomePageHandler, 'main'),
    .....,
    Route('/about', About, 'about')]

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(lst_route, 
    debug=True, config=config)
```

И вот теперь сам вопрос: как можно теперь прыгнуть внутрь каждого элемента списка и добавить дополнительное значение в аргумент элемента списка  одно и то же значение, например: **new_source**:

Route('/about', About, 'about') --> Route('**/new_source**/about', About, 'about')

Есть еще одно предположение - сделать через наследование, но думаю делать переопределение базовых классов google это не совсем правильно... Может есть более правильный маршрут?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел закономерность и решил проблему следующим образом, может кому пригодится:

1. Создал кортеж паарметров:

```
lst_tuple_data_for_Route = [ 
    ('/', HomePageHandler, 'main'),
    .....,
    ('/sign_up', SignUpHandler, 'sign_up')
]
```

2. Написал функцию, которая сохраняет исходный и добавляет аналогичное с новым параметром:

```
def add_new_source(lst_tuple):
    new_lst = []
    new_lst.extend(lst_tuple)
    for element in lst_tuple:
        adr, _Cls, other = element
        new_lst.append(('/new_source' + adr, _Cls, other))
    return new_lst
```

3. Получил новые список кортежей праметров:

```
lst_tuple_data_for_Route = add_new_source(lst_tuple=lst_tuple_data_for_Route)
```

4. Добавил все это в основной список

```
all_lst_WSGIApplication = []
for _Route_ in lst_tuple_data_for_Route:
    all_lst_WSGIApplication.append(Route(*_Route_))
```

5. Ну и вишенка на торте:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(all_lst_WSGIApplication, debug=True, config=config)
```